# Distance from polyhedron to bounding ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polyhedra

How can I find the distance from the edges of the polyhedron to the boundary of the ellipsoid?

The ellipsoid is parameterized by:

$$E = [ x : (x - x_c)^T H (x - x_c) \le m^2 ]  $$

And it covers the polyhedron:

$$ P = [x : a_i^Tx \le b_i, i = 1,...,m] $$

Such that $P \subseteq E$

Comment: This problem as posed, and without any other information is hard to solve, since it's generally a non-convex optimization problem.

Comment: Sorry maybe I omitted some necessary fact, like the fact that $P$ is closed? Or that $x_c$ is an element of $P$? Both of those are true in my problem.